# QT: shaded window effect (lights out)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm opening a modal window from my main window and my interest is to make the background dark so the top window is perfectly visible but the main one looks dark like in the "shade".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show some half-transparent widget over the mainwindow and it will create shadow effect.

For example, such widget.

```
class Overlay : public QWidget
{
public:
  Overlay(QWidget *parent) {
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
  }

protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0, 150)));
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.drawRect(rect());
  }
};
```

Then create this widget, resize and show:

```
overlay_.reset(new Overlay(this));
overlay_->resize(size());
overlay_->setVisible(true);
```

You can play with the shadow color and transperancy by changing brush in paintEvent.
Hope this is the effect you wished.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising! Will try it. There's one line I don't understand: overlay_.reset(new Overlay(this));  what's that one doing?  Where's the reset method ?

Comment: I've tried it without the reset invocation and it opens an overlay but it looks gray no alpha channel so the origina background window is not visible.

Comment: Ok, it's working now with some small changes. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson, good that it works for you. Don't forget to select answer :)

overlay_.reset(new Overlay(this));  - overlay_ is unique_ptr in my code, thats why i used reset function.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to the window manager to add such effect.

For example, KWin and Mutter both have their way to handle dialogs. KWin does shade the main window, and I think Mutter does it too with some additional effect.

In Mac OS, modal window are already have special properties to put it in focus on relation of it's patent window.

The way windows handle this is by forcing the focus on the modal I think. But it really is the window manager's job, and up to the user's preference to choose what effect should be active.