# Create a drawer in QWidget application

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have some kind of drawer in my program (not exactly a drawer that for example we see in android app, I want icon of button inside of the to be visible when the drawer is close, I attached some draft of what Im after)
[image: In close mode]
[image: In open mode]
noticed how the background getting darker when the drawer opened?
I want a drawer that can open as an overlay to the main program page, and when its open put a shadow in all widget behind it...

I can simply create a QWidget and put it in a grid layout beside the main widget that going to hold all other pages, but problem with that is, if I try to open it (with QPropertyAnimation and changing size of it of course) it will just expand in same layer of the main widget, so it will shrink other widget down in order to expand... And this is not good

so Im thinking is it possible with QWidget?

I will attach an example that do what im looking for but in the wrong way that I said before at end of question

/--- example ---/
`mainwindow.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="sideMenu">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>70</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>70</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(83, 86, 94);
border-radius:8;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="menuButton">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>51</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>51</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton { background-color: rgb(197, 255, 134); }
QPushButton:hover { background-color: rgb(172, 222, 117); }
QPushButton:pressed { background-color: rgb(87, 112, 59); }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>OPEN</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="ppage">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>689</width>
        <height>507</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>689</width>
        <height>507</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
border-radius:8;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

`mainwindow.h`

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void toggle_animation();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPropertyAnimation *animation;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->sideMenu, "minimumWidth");

    QObject::connect(ui->menuButton, &QPushButton::released, this, &MainWindow::toggle_animation);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::toggle_animation()
{
    animation->stop();
    if (ui->sideMenu->width() == 70)
    {
        animation->setStartValue(ui->sideMenu->width());
        animation->setEndValue(250);
        ui->menuButton->setText("Close");
    }
    else
    {
        animation->setStartValue(ui->sideMenu->width());
        animation->setEndValue(70);
        ui->menuButton->setText("Open");
    }
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutCubic);
    animation->setDuration(470);
    animation->start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I think this kind of fancy UI would be easier to write in QML, it should definitely be possible with QWidgets. After playing around with some properties in Qt Designer, I think the following will at least make the drawer work as intended.

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="sideMenu">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>70</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(83, 86, 94);
                                border-radius:8;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="menuButton">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>51</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>51</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton { background-color: rgb(197, 255, 134); }
                                            QPushButton:hover { background-color: rgb(172, 222, 117); }
                                            QPushButton:pressed { background-color: rgb(87, 112, 59); }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>OPEN</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="ppage">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>689</width>
        <height>507</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="autoFillBackground">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
                                border-radius:8;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2"/>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
   <zorder>ppage</zorder>
   <zorder>sideMenu</zorder>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The changes here are:

- `MainWindow` starts at a minimum size, but can be made larger;
- The `ppage` widget expands horizontally and vertically, while the `sideMenu` only expands vertically.

The menu will also expand to cover the page if you animate its size like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->sideMenu, "size"); 
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutCubic);
    animation->setDuration(470);

    QObject::connect(ui->menuButton, &QPushButton::released, this, &MainWindow::toggle_animation);
}

void MainWindow::toggle_animation()
{ 
    animation->stop();
    auto const current = ui->sideMenu->size();
    animation->setStartValue(current);
    if (current.width() == 70)
    {
        animation->setEndValue(QSize(250, current.height()));
        ui->menuButton->setText("Close");
    }
    else
    {
        animation->setEndValue(QSize(70, current.height()));
        ui->menuButton->setText("Open");
    }
    animation->start();
}
```

However, this introduces the possibility of resizing the window while the side menu is opened, which bypasses the animation code and makes it snap back unceremoniously to its original width. Fixing this would probably require a different solution, because widgets aren't normally made to overlap and it doesn't play well with layouts. Maybe something like a Dialog would work better.

As for the shaded effect, I'm not sure what the best solution would be, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532241/1719926) has some example code that should work.

Comment: thank you very much, yeah this way it could work but the problem is you make it so much static... can It still resize with the rest of program? and also its seems that hand edited some part of ui file, am i right?

Comment: @file-tracer It also works, in principle, with resizable widgets, see the updated answer. But this creates a problem as both the layout and the animation can adjust the size of the menu. And no, I only used the designer to play with the layouts and the z-order of the widgets.

Comment: thank you very much, yes its much better, but only one other thing, any idea about why the drawer will auto close if we resize the windows?

Comment: well I'm thinking of something, can I put a widget as placeholder and put a widget at top of it? (without any layout) then use the place holder widget to handle program resizing? (just h, because the w is on animation)

Comment: @sanab3343 That's something I was thinking about too, but it would need more C++ code to adjust its own size and position when resizing the window. It's probably best to make it its own QWidget subclass, but I'm not too confident writing one as I haven't used QWidgets in a while.

Comment: @file-tracer: It's because whenever the layout or one of its children is being resized, all of them will be told to redraw themselves. Somehow that doesn't happen when animating the size like this, but at the same time the redraw events will use the original minimum width again.

Comment: yeah it would be a little more work to create, but I believe it would be a better way then other way that used the QPropertyAnimation with QSize...

Comment: one other thing, what about QRubberBand?!

Comment: there isn't any way to fix the redraw problem?

Comment: @file-tracer Sorry for the lateness, but it's probably not possible without writing some custom extensions to Qt C++ classes, which I'm not terribly experienced with. The existing options don't seem to deal well with your intended design. The other option is writing the GUI in QML, in which this is definitely possible with less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've mentioned QML a couple of times, I figured I might as well give it a quick try. Posting this flavour as a separate answer to avoid dumping more code in the other. This is a working prototype:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.4

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 240

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "light grey"

        Item {
            id: content
            width: parent.width - 50
            height: parent.height
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top

            Text {
                font.pixelSize: 30
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: drawer.expanded ? "Opened" : "Closed"
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: overlay
            anchors.fill: content
            opacity: .5
            color: "black"
            visible: drawer.expanded
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: drawer
            property bool expanded: false
            width: 50
            height: parent.height
            radius: 5
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            color: "white"
            function toggle() {
                expanded = !expanded
                width = expanded ? 150 : 50
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: parent.toggle()
            }

            Column {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 5
                spacing: 5
                Repeater {
                    model: 5
                    delegate: drawerItem
                }
            }

            Component {
                id: drawerItem
                RowLayout {
                    Rectangle {
                        width: 40
                        height: 40
                        radius: 20
                        color: "black"
                    }
                    Text {
                        visible: drawer.expanded
                        text: "Item index " + modelData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is already too complicated to be in a single file, but it does demonstrate some of the advantages QML has.

Comment: Also yes, the easiest way of drawing a circle in QML is using a `Rectangle`!